# How to do Parsing in j2me(java)

Tags: java-me, midp-2.0

i want to extract the

iframe tag "src" value from the below url
http://www.teluguone.com/videos/single/comedy/Comedy-Express-464---Back-to-Back---Comedy-Scenes-14727.html

iframe width="640" height="380" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XJDw2T1nGJQ"frameborder="0"

allowfullscreen/iframe

How can i achieve it in j2me?htmlparser ,Jericho ,Jsoup parser are not supported in j2me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have the html source stored in a `String` variable called htmlPage.

```
int iFrameIndex = htmlPage.indexOf("iframe");
int srcIndex = htmlPage.indexOf("src", iFrameIndex);
int httpIndex = htmlPage.indexOf("http", srcIndex);
int quotesIndex = htmlPage.indexOf("\"", httpIndex);
String srcUrl = htmlPage.substring(httpIndex, quotesIndex);
```