# How to Extract Text from Div Tag From Html in java

Tags: java, java-me, html-parsing

Hi,

I want to extract text between `div` tag

```
<div class="innercontenttxt"> 
<p>img border="1" align="left" height="170" width="324" vspace="3" hspace="2" src="/tmdbuserfiles/ramdev-balakrishna(1).jpg" alt="ramdev aide remanded, lakrishna acharya judicial remand, ramdev aide fake passport case, baba ramdev assistant judicial custody, balakrishna sent to judicial custody, yoga guru ramdev assistant remanded, yoga guru ramdev assistant balakrishna" />
Yoga guru Ramdev's aide Balakrishna Acharya remanded to 14 days judicial custody in a fake passport on Saturday. He was arrested yesterday after he failed to appear at a Dehradun court.
    <br />
    <br />
     Balakrishna Acharya, who is basically a Nepalese citizen, 
     is alleged to have submitted fake documents to procure a passport. 
     When he failed to appear in Dehradun court in connection with the case,
</p>  
</div>
```

After extracting the result should be:

> ramdev aide alakrishna Acharya remanded to 14 days
>   judicial custody in a fake passport on Saturday. He was arrested
>   yesterday after he failed to appear at a Dehradun court.Balakrishna
>   Acharya, who is basically a Nepalese citizen, is alleged to have
>   submitted fake documents to procure a passport. When he failed to
>   appear in Dehradun court in connection with the case, the court had
>   issued a non-bailable warrant and subsequently arrested him yesterday.

Comment: I have tried different HTML Parsers like Jericho HTML Parser ,HTML Parser ,J soup Parser But those all are not supported in j2me

Comment: you need a general solution to parse `div` tags or specific to your case ?

Comment: Is any parser available with out using java.net.url class for my case?Can u help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem seems similiar to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626040/how-to-do-parsing-in-j2mejava/11630153#11630153).

Assuming you already have the html source stored in a String variable called htmlPage.

```
int divIndex = htmlPage.indexOf("<div");
divIndex = htmlPage.indexOf(">", divIndex);

int endDivIndex = htmlPage.indexOf("</div>", divIndex);
String content = htmlPage.substring(divIndex + 1, endDivIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try some of the Java HTML parser libraries

HTML Parser - http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net

jsoup - http://jsoup.org/

Comment: Hii,this i am developing for j2me application,there ,i am not having java.net.url class,so other than this class any  tell me any parsers  avilable for my need...